# Converting column text in a data frame into multiple lines inside a single a row

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix

I would like to create a table where will see the topic number and which objects are related with that which I think I have done. The reproducible code is below:

```
ash<-(matrix(c(4,2,NA,9,3,8,NA,NA,1,5,6,7),nrow=3, byrow=TRUE))
old<-seq(1:9)
ash2<-c("jegjgqe","hdd","odew","dhjs","ddj","hdiwhek","dij","jsosaeo")
ash[] <-  ash2[as.matrix(ash)]
tbl<-data.frame(Topic_no = paste('Topic', seq_len(nrow(ash))), Objects_Transcripts =  apply(ash, 1, function(x) toString(x[complete.cases(x)])))
tbl

  Topic_no        Objects_Transcripts
1  Topic 1                  dhjs, hdd
2  Topic 2              odew, jsosaeo
3  Topic 3 jegjgqe, ddj, hdiwhek, dij
```

But one thing I want is not showing more than two names in one line in the Object_Transcripts column which means I want to create multiple lines in a single row where each line will show only two names and after two names it will automatically create another line which will include the next two names and so on.

Answer (score 1):

We could use `unite` after converting the `matrix` to `data.frame`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
ash %>%
   as.data.frame %>%
   mutate(Topic_no = str_c('Topic', row_number())) %>%
   unite(Object_Transcripts, V1:V4, na.rm = TRUE, sep=", ") %>%
   select(Topic_no, Object_Transcripts)
```

-output

```
 Topic_no         Object_Transcripts
1   Topic1                  dhjs, hdd
2   Topic2              odew, jsosaeo
3   Topic3 jegjgqe, ddj, hdiwhek, dij
```

---

If we need a nexline (`\n`) between each 2 elements

```
library(purrr)
ash %>%
    as.data.frame %>%
    mutate(Topic_no = str_c('Topic', row_number()), .before = 1) %>% 
    pivot_longer(cols = -Topic_no, values_drop_na = TRUE) %>%   
    group_by(Topic_no) %>%
    group_by(grp = as.integer(gl(n(), 2, n())), .add = TRUE) %>%  
    summarise(Object_Transcripts = toString(value), .groups = 'drop_last') %>% 
    summarise(Object_Transcripts = str_c(Object_Transcripts, collapse="\n"))
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  Topic_no Object_Transcripts          
  <chr>    <chr>                       
1 Topic1   "dhjs, hdd"                 
2 Topic2   "odew, jsosaeo"             
3 Topic3   "jegjgqe, ddj\nhdiwhek, dij"
```

If it is okay to have multiple rows, then remove the last `summarise` statement

```
ash %>%
     as.data.frame %>%
     mutate(Topic_no = str_c('Topic', row_number()), .before = 1) %>% 
     pivot_longer(cols = -Topic_no, values_drop_na = TRUE) %>%   
     group_by(Topic_no) %>%
     group_by(grp = as.integer(gl(n(), 2, n())), .add = TRUE) %>%  
     summarise(Object_Transcripts = toString(value), .groups = 'drop_last')
# A tibble: 4 x 3
# Groups:   Topic_no [3]
  Topic_no   grp Object_Transcripts
  <chr>    <int> <chr>             
1 Topic1       1 dhjs, hdd         
2 Topic2       2 odew, jsosaeo     
3 Topic3       3 jegjgqe, ddj      
4 Topic3       4 hdiwhek, dij
```

Comment: When I run, it gives error, Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `Topic_no`.
x could not find function "str_c"
i Input `Topic_no` is `str_c("Topic", row_number())`.

Comment: No worry, but the fact is I want to get two names in one line of the transcript object column. Like for the 3rd row, I want jegjgqe, ddj at first line and hdiwhek, dij in the second line and so on(obviously in the same row but multiple lines).

Comment: I looked at your expected and it is the same I am getting (`obviously in the same row but multiple lines)` - can you please reread your statement before typing - thanks)

Comment: `R` wouldn't allow multiple lines in a single row.  If you meant to paste with `\n`, that is possible

Comment: sorry my output is not the expected thing, It is the thing I got, sorry for misunderstanding. I can't reproduce a example that I want as my final table. I don't know if I expain now clearly. So for the given example , what I want in the 3rd row of Object_transcript column, First line: jegjgqe, ddj, Second line: hdiwhek, dij like this. And if we have another name we will add third line and so on. And it can happens in  multiple rows.

Comment: But using \n still it doesn't show in next line, it's just appear as first line \n second line. Is it not possible to do? is there anyway we could implement cat comment to show multiple lines in a single row?

Comment: `cat` doesn't have return type. It is just for printing

Comment: I am not sure whether this is just for printing.  Then, you can use many  packages such as `kable, kableExtra, formattable, gt, ...` which would accept the `\n` for printing in next row

Comment: Thanks, but I would need return type. But if we allow multiple rows like you did in the last one, can we make the topic_no column where the topic1/2/3 would appears only in the first time and rest of the following cells for the same topic would be blank. Like for the given example, in the topic_no cell in 4th row would be blank rather than telling Topic3?

Answer (score 0):

Use `separate_rows` to split comma-separated values in different rows. For each topic create group of 2 words and combine them. Replace repeated topics with blanks.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

tbl %>%
  separate_rows(Objects_Transcripts, sep = ',\\s*') %>%
  group_by(Topic_no) %>%
  group_by(grp = ceiling(row_number()/2), .add = TRUE) %>%
  summarise(Objects_Transcripts = toString(Objects_Transcripts)) %>%
  mutate(Topic_no = replace(Topic_no, -1, '')) %>%
  ungroup %>% select(-grp)

#  Topic_no  Objects_Transcripts
#  <chr>     <chr>              
#1 "Topic 1" dhjs, hdd          
#2 "Topic 2" odew, jsosaeo      
#3 "Topic 3" jegjgqe, ddj       
#4 ""        hdiwhek, dij
```

---

If you want to use this for display purposes there are different packages which can help you combine such rows into one. For example with `gt` -

```
library(gt)

tbl %>%
  separate_rows(Objects_Transcripts, sep = ',\\s*') %>%
  group_by(Topic_no) %>%
  group_by(grp = ceiling(row_number()/2), .add = TRUE) %>%
  summarise(Objects_Transcripts = toString(Objects_Transcripts)) %>%
  ungroup %>% select(-grp) %>%
  gt(groupname_col = 'Topic_no')
```

[image]